# Running Flask on bash: Could not import "app"

Tags: python, flask

I made this code on Flask:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "hi"
```

Even so, fi I try to run it with `flask run` it shows this message:

```
* Serving Flask app "app.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: Could not import "app".
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: 
App structure:

```
website/
  | - app.py
```

Comment: Is there another file used in your project ?

Comment: No files. I was trying the basic tutorial, and I could not find what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "hi"


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=30006, debug=True)
```

Run in the same directory where this code is placed.

```
python3 file_name.py
```

You can access it on

```
http://0.0.0.0:30006/
```

[image: Working screenshot]

Comment: Tried it and the following error was added:
```/usr/bin/python3.7: can't open file '/home/cmuniz/Documents/app.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory```
But I'm executing the file from  `Documents/website/app.py`.

Comment: can you please list down the file at `/home/cmuniz/Documents` by using `ll` terminal command?

Comment: There is no issue with your flask code. The error is due to the path. It will be solved if the flask code accessible to python3. plus you can test your code using [python online editor]:https://repl.it/languages/python3

Comment: @CaioMuniz updated answer with a working screenshot of flask server. thanks

Comment: that did not work out in my computer, no matter if I use python, python3 or python3.7

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured a virtualenv for your project, you have to activate the virtualenv with this command

```
>>>env\scripts\activate
```

Then make sure you are in the same directory where your app.py is located then use this commands

```
env>>>Set FLASK_APP=app.py 
env>>>Set FLASK_ENVIRONMENT=development
env>>>flask run
```

keep cracking
**note if you are on linux use 'export' instead of 'set'

Answer (score 0):

If you do not provide the correct path, Flask will not be able to import your app. Check if you are inside the right folder with

```
pwd
```

You might see something like (I use MacOS so it might appear differently on your end if you use another OS)

```
/Users/your_username/Desktop/current_file
```

If you are not at the correct file, app, you can add in the path for that file, say the website file is inside your current_file. Then:

```
 export FLASK_APP=/Users/your_username/Desktop/current_file/website/app.py
```

Then do `flask run` . Hope this helped!