# Flask Error in Python: "Could not import webapp"

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to run flask, however, whenever I type in [flask run] it gives me an error: `Could not import webapp`. For reference, I am using Visual Studio Code and am running the following code:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello, world!"
```

I get the following error message:

```
 * Serving Flask app "webapp"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
Error: Could not import "webapp".
```

Comment: please provide stps how you are running flask

Answer (score 2):

Your FLASK_APP variable is probably not correctly configured. Could you make sure that:

1. Your file (the one with this code) is named webapp.py OR
2. alternatively, that your FLASK_APP variable (however you set it) is set to the filename of the file containing this code.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re setting the FLASK_ENV variable using a .flaskenv or simply using the shell, make sure you don’t have any spelling errors. It’s a mistake that’s so simple it often gets overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

this error is because you set `FLASK_APP` environmental variable and your script name is different.

I suggest you to:

1. change your script name (the file where you have to write given code )to webapp.py
2. set environment variable `FLASK_APP` to your script name, ie
   in windows `set FLASK_APP=<script-name>` or in ubuntu(Linux) `export FLASK_APP=<script-name>`

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the documentation is incorrect in the [VS Code tutorial for Flask](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask).

1. To correct this error, set `FLASK_APP` to `hello_app.webapp` in the tutorial:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Flask",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "hello_app.webapp"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger",
                "--no-reload"
            ],
            "jinja": true
        }
    ]
}
```

2. In terminal, run `export set FLASK_APP=hello_app.webapp` instead of `export set FLASK_APP=webapp` as mentioned in the tutorial.
3. Finally, run `python3 -m flask run`

Answer (score 0):

Forget the flask command line launcher and do as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60356233/1410035) says:

Add these lines to your python script:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=30006, debug=True)
```

> Run in the same directory where this code is placed.
>
> ```
> python3 file_name.py
> ```
>
> You can access it on
>
> ```
> http://0.0.0.0:30006/
> ```

For you, it looks like you named your file `webapp.py` so you'd run:

```
python webapp.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you run the app, check your working directory/base  folder.

```
(base) D:\Pyl\GitHubRepo\FlaskApp\FlaskApp>flask run
```

The same folder `(D:\Pyl\GitHubRepo\FlaskApp\FlaskApp)` should contain **app.py file**

`app.py` file is the script file you want to run.
If it does not work: do this `set FLASK_APP=app` (In windows)
here 'app' is your script file name without py extension.
Also, if you change script name, you need to reset the FLASK_APP variable.